# Regex for match and replace substring

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, string

We have logging functionality to log all the requests and now I want to hide some sensitive data from the request body.

```
string body = null;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream))
{
    request.InputStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(body))
{
    _logger.NameValueLogger.Add("body", RemoveSensitiveData(body));
}
```

Example for Body content:

*"Id=12345&Id=&Name=TestName&AddressLine1=1232+test+&AddressLine2=sdf&City=abcd"*

Now in **RemoveSensitiveData()** I want to search for Name and replace the name value "TestName" to "*****"

Also if there are any other fields I want to hide along with name, I have to replace them too.

Can anyone please suggest best approach to handle this?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I would absolutely learn some very basic regular expression syntax and use a regex.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have several fields that I have to hide from entire application, for example :  string hiddenFieldsList = "Name|AddressLine1|AccountNumber|BorrowName|CoBorrowName|CheckNumber|CheckAmount"; 
So Is there any better way to do this instead of hardcoding into a string?

Comment: You could do that with a regex, yes. I'm glad you've found somebody to do all your work for you.

Comment: Regex part I got it, I am passing this string into Regex.. Is there any better way to do this instead of hardcoding into a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string RemoveSensitiveData(string value) => Regex.Replace(value, "((^|&)(Name|OtherSensitiveData)=)[^&]+", m => m.Groups[1].Value + "*****")
```

edit: added `(^|&)` ensure full match

Comment: No, it might overfire in case of `TestName=something`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ty

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "mask" some parameter with a fixed amount of asterisks you may use a simple `Regex.Replace` with no MatchEvaluator:

```
string RemoveSensitiveData(string value) => 
    Regex.Replace(value, "((?:&|^)(?:Name|OtherSensitiveData)=)[^&]+", "$1*****")
```

If you plan to replace with the same amount of asterisks use

```
string RemoveSensitiveData(string value) =>
    Regex.Replace(value, "((?:&|^)(?:Name|OtherSensitiveData)=)([^&]+)", m =>
        $"{m.Groups[1].Value}{new String('*', m.Groups[2].Value.Length)}")
```

**Regex details**

- `((?:&|^)(?:Name|OtherSensitiveData)=)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:&|^)` -  a non-capturing group matching either a `&` char or start of string (it can be replaced with `(?<![^&])`)
  - `(?:Name|OtherSensitiveData)` - a non-capturing group matching either `Name` or `OtherSensitiveData` substrings
  - `=` - an equal sign
- `([^&]+)` - Group 2: any 1+ chars other than `&`.

See the [C# demo:](https://ideone.com/1j9FDL)

```
var value = "Id=12345&Id=&Name=TestName&AddressLine1=1232+test+&AddressLine2=sdf&City=abcd";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(value, "((?:&|^)(?:Name|OtherSensitiveData)=)[^&]+", "$1*****"));
// => Id=12345&Id=&Name=*****&AddressLine1=1232+test+&AddressLine2=sdf&City=abcd
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(value, "((?:&|^)(?:Name|OtherSensitiveData)=)([^&]+)", m =>
        $"{m.Groups[1].Value}{new String('*', m.Groups[2].Value.Length)}"));
// => Id=12345&Id=&Name=********&AddressLine1=1232+test+&AddressLine2=sdf&City=abcd
```